# C++ Expression Must Have Class Type

Tags: c++, vector

Dear helpful StackOverflow users, 
   I am having trouble with this code in the specific line in the function        `Remove_Student(int section_id, int student_id)`:

```
"(*iter).student_id[i].erase();".
```

The error message I am receiving is expression must have a class type.  Left of .erase must have a class/struct/union.  However, in my Section class I have already defined student_id as a vector of ints.  Please, any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot figure out why this is not working.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Section
{
public:
friend class University;


private:
    int section_id;
    string course_id;
    string instructor;
    vector<string> meeting_time;
    vector<int> student_id;
    string location;


};








#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Section.h"
#include "misc.h"

using namespace std;

class University{
public: 
    string Add_Section(int section_id, string course_id, string instructor, string location){
        Section newSection;
        newSection.section_id = section_id;
        newSection.course_id = course_id;
        newSection.instructor = instructor;
        newSection.location = location;
        sections.push_back(newSection);
        return intToString(section_id) + "was added\n";
    }


    string Remove_Student(int section_id, int student_id)
    {
        vector<Section>::iterator iter;
        iter = sections.begin();
        while (iter != sections.end())
        {
            if (section_id == (*iter).section_id)
            {
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (*iter).student_id.size(); i++)
                {
                    if ((*iter).student_id[i] == student_id)
                    {
                        (*iter).student_id[i].erase();
                        return student_id + " was removed.\n";
                    }
                }
                return intToString(student_id) + " was not found.\n";
            }

            else
            {
                iter++;
            }

        }
        return intToString(section_id) + " was not found.\n";
    }



private:
    vector<Section> sections;

};
```

Comment: If `student_id` is a `vector<int>` then `student_id[i]` is an `int`, and that has no member functions. Also note that `std::vector::erase` has no overloads with no parameters.

Comment: Read on how [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) should be called.

Comment: @remyabel I have a function directly above this where it deletes a vector of meeting times.  The meeting times are string but erase has no parameters and works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(*iter).student_id[i]` refers to an `int`, you probably want something like:

```
(*iter).student_id.erase((*iter).student_id.begin() + i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although a hand-written loop is good for learning purposes, it's hard to read and to maintain. Mistakes are easily made. A preferred approach is to use methods from the standard library, in particular `std::remove`. The erase-remove idiom simplifies your code tremendously. Here's an example:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 1, 2, 1};
    std::vector<int>::iterator remove_it = std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
    if (remove_it == v.end()) std::cout << "Student not found.\n";
    else
    {
        v.erase(remove_it, v.end());
        std::cout << "Student removed.\n";
    }
}
```

`sdt::remove` returns an iterator to the new end of the range. If it uses `std::find` internally, `std::find` returns an iterator to the end of the range if nothing was found.